Volume by Shells
I was messing around with some MIT OpenCourseWare problems and got the question:
Assume that $0 < a < b.$ Revolve the disk $(x − b)^2 + y^2 \leq a^2$ around the y axis. This doughnut shape is known as a torus.
Set up the integral for volume using integration dx
Now, I've worked out the integral of it in my head to be:
$$ 4\pi b \int_{b-a}^{b+a} \sqrt{a^2-(x-b)^2} dx $$
I justified this by saying that since it's a circle, it's symmetrical. Therefore, the radius for the two y values can be "averaged" out to each having a radius of b.
However, the solution provides a completely different perspective which I don't understand. It wrote that the integral should be:
$$ \int_{b-a}^{b+a} 4\pi x \sqrt{a^2-(x-b)^2} dx $$
and when using $ z = x-b $, the equation becomes identical for the integral using y in which the final equation is:
$$ \int_{-a}^{a} 4\pi b \sqrt{a^2-z^2} dx $$
Now, I completely understood the substituting part, but I don't understand how you could get away with using $x$ in the second equation. If we would graph out a small cylinder of width $dx$ and a radius of x for shells, certainly the outer circumference (radius of $x+dx$) is bigger than the inner circumference (radius of $x$). Therefore, it needs to be averaged out to have a radius of $ x+1/2dx $. In fact, this is one of the reasons it took me a long time to set up the integral because I do not know how to get rid of this $1/2dx$ in the integral.
So, how is this allowed in integrals intuitively?

Very much sorry for the poor drawing.

Please do not use text in MathJax - even with $\text{foo}$ it still looks out of place.

Sorry, I'm new to the site and do not know the usual conventions for asking questions.

The formula for the volume by shells is $$ 2\pi \int_a ^b r(x) h(x) \ dx$$ where $r$ is the shell radius and $h$ the shell height. In the solution, the "extra" $x$ is there because it serves as the shell radius. Given a point $x$ in the domain of integration, it is the distance from that point to the axis of rotation.
The problem with your "averaging" approach is that it would reduce each small shell to be of the same radius, which is certainly not the case. Each radius varies, so that must be taken into account.

Yes, it would reduce each small shell to be of the same radius. However, since there are 2 x-values for a single y-value, the two x-values can be averaged out so that we can use a single x-value for both x-values with the same y-value. Plus, I don't see how we can use the "extra" x there for each small shell because each shell has an outer and inner circumference as shown above. Therefore, I figured that we need to average the two circumferences which involves averaging the two radius for each circumference.

That doesn't work - the two mirror shells have the same height but are at different radii. You need to account for this for the volume!

Yes there's two radii, but I figured you can average the two radii to a single radius for both shells so that when calculating both shells with the same radius, it would be the same as calculating both shells with different radii. It seems also that my logic works as if you substituted my integral with $z = x-b$, it is the exact same as the solution. However, my main question though is why is $x$ allowed in the integral? If you see my drawing, the inner circumference is shorter than the outer circumference. Therefore, the length of the shell won't be x when calculating the volume of the shell.

Again - each radius varies. You cannot just average them out by symmetry. If this were the case, then you'd be approximating the torus by a cylinder of some sort, which is not correct. It seems you're trying to invoke the mean value theorem for integrals without fully understanding it.

After thinking about it (sorry for the long wait) and looking at the internet, it seems that using $x$ is possible because we are using middle Riemann sum for calculating the volume. I thought this was impossible because you had to change the integral to fit this sum, but it seems like you are trying to say that there's no problem doing this using $x$. I'm still not sure about my way being incorrect because it seems like it works perfectly fine to solve the problem. I've seen some posts in the internet and it seems like you indeed approximate the torus using a hollow cylinder.

No matter what tag you use in the Riemann sum, it still produces the same integral. Try doing your "averaging" for other shapes - does it still work? You cannot average variable quantities in this way unless you invoke the mean value theorem for integrals in a particular way. This is all I will say on the subject.
